# Adding a View makes a ListView within a fragment to refresh

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

This might be a little bit hard to explain, so the best way I can think of, is providing you a Video showing up the issue.

In the Video I show myself scrolling listview, and after 5 seconds, a View is created and added inside that holder in the bottom. In that moment, listview is refreshed.

http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=vpz0k8%3E&s=8#.U0VrIvl_t8E

The issue is the following:

I've an Activity with a layout that consists of a:

1. Fragment (above RelativeLayout), match parent, match parent.
2. RelativeLayout, as wrap content.

The fragment displays a ListView with animations for every row.

If I add a View on the "RelativeLayout", it makes the fragment to readjust to the new size, as it's set above this RelativeLayout, so every Row is rebuilt again.

Do you guys think in any way to avoid this?

**EDIT: Sourcecode:**
https://bitbucket.org/sergicast/listview-animated-buggy

Comment: Try adding this view to the footer of a listview and see what happens. There might be a possibility that it doesnt refresh the listview.

Comment: View is generated by the activity, and fragment shouldn't care about it. That's why it's not added as a row within the listview. Also that I want to add it in the bottom, no matter if user scrolls or not.

Comment: I think you should read a little about footers. Readjustments are always made if you add anything on runtime. Please take a look at the link, http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.maxaller.name%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2010%2F05%2Flistview_footer_scrolling.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.maxaller.name%2F2010%2F05%2Fattaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview%2F&h=486&w=326&tbnid=hJk1wZfLxhrhiM%3A&zoom=1&docid=ZzAfhS2mGIhMmM&ei=u5lFU9qvLYHxhQen8oCAAg&tbm=isch&ved=0CFgQhBwwAQ&iact=rc&dur=1275&page=1&start=0&ndsp=38 . This is a link to a pic showing a footer (ok button)

Comment: The link you provided actually does something I'm already doing. A container that holds Spinner - ListView - Button. My issue is happening because of: Fragment(ListView Inside) - View

Comment: I've attached sourcecode so you can compile and check it by your own.

Comment: The `TextView` that you add below the `Fragment` holding the `ListView` causes it's parent to relayout the `Fragment`. The `Fragment` does a relayout on the `ListView` in turn, which causes the `Adapter` to reissue the animation upon request. What you need to do to avoid this is to create a flag in the `Adapter` for the animation and a method for disabling it in the `Fragment`, and then disable the animation before adding the footer `TextView` and re-enable it afterwards. In fact, you should only enable the animation during scrolling, as the `ListView` could be refreshed in other cases also.

Comment: Before your comment, I've tried disabling the animation as a flag, but this is not as clean as i'd like to. The thing about "just enable when scrolling" seems way better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't start the animation if the layout process for the added footer view is running. The end of the layout process can be determined using the ViewTreeObserver (the start obviously starts with adding the footer view):

```
    hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = holder.getViewTreeObserver();
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    holder.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    mIgnoreAnimation = false;
                }
            });

            mIgnoreAnimation = true;
            holder.addView(viewToAdd);
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Add this method to your Activity:

```
public boolean ignoreAnimation() {
    return mIgnoreAnimation;
}
```

And check it in your Fragment:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Context context = FragmentTest.this.getActivity();

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText("Pos: " + position);
    tv.setTextSize(35f);

    if (runAnimation()) {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.animation);
        tv.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    return tv;
}

private boolean runAnimation() {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null && activity instanceof MainActivity) {
        return ! ((MainActivity)activity).ignoreAnimation();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Of course the whole Activity - Fragment communication can be improved considerably but the example gives you the idea how to solve the problem in general.

While it prevents the animation from being started, it doesn't prevent the ListView from being refreshed although the user won't notice. If you are concerned about performance you can improve the Adapter code by re-using the views:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Context context = FragmentTest.this.getActivity();
    TextView tv = null;
    if (convertView != null && convertView instanceof TextView) {
        tv = (TextView) convertView;
    }
    else {
        tv = new TextView(context);
    }
```

Comment: I wonder if your approach would stop the ListView from being invalidated and redrawn in the conditions set by the OP

Comment: If you had read my answer you'd know it doesn't but I guess your question is just a rhetorical one... I don't think the problem is the redraw of the ListView but the artifacts visible to the user (the animations). Without those the user won't notice anything. But let the OP decide what's the better solution, having a fixed size view placed on the screen (taking away space from the actual ListView) or my solution.

Comment: Not the rhetorical one. I was curious if your workaround really makes a redrawal process transparent to user - apart from the animation provided by OP. As for my solution - I do not consider it a good one in terms of the UI, I just made an effort to describe the roots of the problem and show *one* possible way of handling all this. Fast and dirty :)

Comment: It does make it transparent to the user (I tested it)

Comment: I was actually thinking about a way to prevent the redraw from happening at all (using a custom ListView that ignores certain "events" like calls to invalidate() or requestLayout() but 1) that didn't work and 2) it might not be a good idea to suppress the layout process because there's a reason it runs when a new View is added to the layout and it would probably have undesired side effects to suppress it.

Comment: Check my new "ddd" method. http://i.imgur.com/JsS1D47.png Looks clean, and works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can think of a possible way to solve this.

Your problem is:

1. You have set layout params of your `holder` to wrap_content. By default, when it has no content, it is "zero-sized" somewhere in the bottom and invisible to you (not *invisible* in terms of Android, though, sic!)
2. When you add a View to this `holder`, the framework understands, that the size of your `holder` container is different now. But this container is a child of another container - your **root** `RelativeLayout`, which, in turn, contains another child - your `<fragment>`.
3. Thus, framework decides, the root container alongside with its children should get laid out again. That's why your list gets invalidated and redrawn.

To fix the issue with list getting invalidated and redrawn, simply specify some fixed layout parameters to your `holder`. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

That will prevent the list from being redrawn. But in that case you'll get your `holder` displayed from the very beginning.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. This is the expected behavior of **RelativeLayout**

You are adding the **ListView** *Fragment* and TextView into a RelativeLayout, So whenever there is a change in the child view dimension, will affect the other child in the RelativeLayout.

So here when you add a new TexView , the other child Fragment is affected even though its height is match_parent.

You can fix this only by changing the parent layout to **LinearLayout**.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow morning =)

Comment: Just tried, and same issue is happening, this is currently the layout: http://pastebin.com/Wz0H8hv9